# The "-ing" form of a verb and indefinite article

Tags: grammaticality, indefinite-articles, ing, omissibility

> If celebrities visit public places, such as malls and bars, people
> will crowd them demanding for a picture or autograph.

1: Why did the writer use the "-ing" form of the verb "demand"? Is there any rule for this?

2: Why there was no article before the word "autograph"?

Comment: Here, 'demanding ... a picture or autograph' is an adjunct (tacked-on information), specifically an ing-clause modifying the main clause ('people will crowd them'). The second article ('an') would be preferred by some, but the original is a deleted form some would use.

Comment: Is it really modifying the main clause _people will crowd them_?  I parse it as modifying the subject _people_.  Certainly if it was _people will crowd them getting in the way_, I'd take _getting in the way_ to be applying to _people_, not the whole clause.

Comment: @tea-and-cake I see the demanding as semantically dependent on the crowding. ' ... people will crowd [round] them in order to demand a picture or autograph'. It would be different with ' ... people will crowd them, not failing to recognise them'. Though the ing-clause would probably be better switched to postnominal position if the noun is intended to be modified.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Interesting point!  It looks like there's an ambiguity in that structure that can only be resolved by the semantics.  (I thought at first that maybe the presence or otherwise of a comma was relevant, but you could insert a comma in OP's sentence before _demanding_ and it wouldn't change anything.)

Comment: @tea-and-cake deadrat looks at this issue at [Can a participle phrase/clause modify a clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264669/can-a-participle-phrase-modify-a-clause)

Comment: In 1. A depictive adjunct, to be precise, giving descriptive information about "people" -- A modifier in clause structure.

Comment: @tea-and-cake It doesn't modify "people", but is a modifier in clause structure, i.e. it modifies the verb phrase. It does of course _refer_ to "people", and hence is best described as a depictive adjunct, giving descriptive information about "people"; note that it is interpreted with progressive aspectuality: "people will be demanding a picture or autograph".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ***Demanding for a picture or autograph*** is a participial construction used as an ***[adverbial clause](https://www.twinkl.co.uk/teaching-wiki/adverbial-phrase-clause)*** (containing an [adverbial participle](https://www.englishgrammar.org/grammar-terms-adverb-adverb-phrases-adverb-clauses-adverbial-participles/)) modifying *will crowd* to express the ***reason*** why *people will crowd the celebrities*, though others might argue that this is an adverbial of purpose.
2. ***A picture or autograph***: the indefinite article ***an*** was [omitted](https://www.englishbix.com/omission-rules-for-a-and-an-with-examples/) before ***autograph*** probably to include ***picture*** and ***autograph*** into one category: *the type of thing fans may ask for*.

Comment: Is 'to demand for something' idiomatic? Grammatical?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good point, _for_ got stuck probably by analogy with _ask for_. But [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=demanding+for%2C+demanding+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdemanding%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdemanding%20that%3B%2Cc0) records it. And yes, it is odd to say that you "demand an autograph from a celebrity", it would be very haughty, unacceptable in fact. But maybe it was used to show that people _**force**_ themselves on celebrities at times.

Comment: In 1. A depictive adjunct, to be precise, giving descriptive information about "people". And in 2, an NP coordination determined by "a".