# What is the grammar rules that governs the words highlighted?

Tags: grammar, clauses

This sentence is an excerpt from *The Economist* website.

> The Kremlin denied the advance, **saying that Russian troops had repelled Ukrainian attacks in the region**.

What is the grammatical rule that's governing the *"saying that Russian troops had repelled Ukrainian attacks in the region"* in the sentence above?

I've been looking into the types of clauses to find any applications that match this, but I think I'm lost.

Comment: The non-finite gerund-participial _saying_ clause is a supplementary adjunct. Supplements are loosely attached expressions set off by intonation (and usually punctuation) presenting supplementary, non-integrated content.

Comment: Or to put it slightly more simply, it's a [participle clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/c1-grammar/participle-clauses). Can't you work out what it means? What information do you need?

Comment: @StuartF I said it was a participial clause.

Comment: Bill and Stuart replied, choosing to comment rather than answer.

Comment: @DjinTonic The question is such a simple one that a comment is all that is required to handle it.

Comment: @BillJ, Yes, of course, but I couldn't resist adding another example :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a participle phrase modify a clause?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264669/can-a-participle-phrase-modify-a-clause) Examples given: _A major accident occurred on our bus's route to school, making us late for class._ // _The gas tank exploded, sending shrapnel through the air._ //// In addition to BillJ's syntactic analysis, one could add that semantically, this is an adjunct used for restatement / reinforcement / expansion.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613256/2085).

Answer (score 0):

It adds supplementary info to the matrix clause and isn't explicitly connected to the matrix clause with any kind of connector word.

In such a clause, the participle on a semantic level indicates that the info  added in the non-finite clause is relevant to the matrix clause as it occurred *during the same time-frame* as the action or event of the matrix clause. The time-frame is that of the matrix clause.

> Yesterday, he collapsed into the easy chair, saying "I am exhausted".
>
> And tomorrow he will collapse into the easy chair, saying "I am exhausted."